# Tablet app doesn't fill the screen completely

Tags: android, layout, tablet

[image]

What is the problem that Hello app, just with some other text doesn't fill the whole screen ?

The properties of textview widget are both fill_parent...

How can I use the entire screen of the tablet for my application >?

the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="just small area"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I do not think it is xml issue ..., but see in my edits I posted the main.xml

Comment: fill_parent was deprecated.  As from API level 8 you should use match_parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to AndroidManifest file.

```
<supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: If you are using Android 2.2+ , i.e. in AndroidManifest file if its specified that target SDK version is 8 or above , you don't need to include support screen, Framework will take care.

Comment: on tablets you usually want targetSDK to 11 even, which isnt set either looking at the picture in the question

Comment: He might be using code which was developed for 1.6+ on tablet.

Comment: Note: I still needed the manifest file change with Android 2.2 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Some times Android has difficulties to choose the specific graphics to use.
I have the same problem and i solved it by using special drawable directory - 
drawable-hdpi-1200x650.